# QAF-Cucumber with Junit : Maven Install throwing error at ConfigurationManager

Tags: maven, junit, cucumber, qaf

we are using QAF-Cucumber and Junit, have added the dependency for the same in our POM.xml

```
     <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId> 
     <artifactId>qaf-cucumber</artifactId> 
     <version>2.1.15</version> 
     <scope>test</scope> 
  </dependency>
```

and have added the plugin information in the cucumber runner plugin = { "com.qmetry.qaf.automation.cucumber.QAFCucumberPlugin" }

on doing an Maven Install, getting error

'''

```
enter code here
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.983 sec <<< FAILURE!
   initializationError()  Time elapsed: 0.017 sec  <<< ERROR!
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/qmetry/qaf/automation/core/ConfigurationManager
   at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.cucumber.Bdd2Compiler.lambda$addMetaData$4(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
   at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
   at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
   at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
   at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.cucumber.Bdd2Compiler.addMetaData(Unknown Source)
   at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.cucumber.Bdd2Compiler.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
   at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.cucumber.Bdd2Compiler.compile(Unknown Source)
   at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.compilePickles(FeatureParser.java:59)
   at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureParser.parseResource(FeatureParser.java:37)
   at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureBuilder.parse(FeatureBuilder.java:24)
   at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureLoader.loadFromFeaturePath(FeatureLoader.java:35)
   at io.cucumber.core.feature.FeatureLoader.load(FeatureLoader.java:22)
   at io.cucumber.core.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.get(FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.java:34)
   at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:143)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at 

sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
  at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
  at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
  at 

   ... 42 more
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have dependency missing in your pom. Try adding QAF dependency, for example:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
        <artifactId>qaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.15</version>
</dependency>
```